# Background notification sounds that plays even when the window is minimized

Tags: javascript, facebook, audio, notifications, chat

I've been working on this for a while and digging around various bits of code and different aporaches to playing sounds whilst a window is minimized or another tab is selected including SWF files and javascript but can't seem to find anything that works like the Facebook chat notification sounds work.

I'm thinking it works in JavaScript as that seems to be what Facebook likes but i'm open to try anything!

I'd love to hear everyone's ideas regarding this and if you don't know what I mean, open facebook, start chatting to someone that will reply and minimize the browser window whilst you wait and you'll hear the notification sound even though the window is minimized!

Comment: What is wrong with solutions you have tried so far? It is hard for me to believe that sound played via flash or html5 AUDIO stops paying when you minimize the browser window or change the tab.

Comment: @kdzwinel every time I switch browser tabs and an event happens in the background there are no sounds played! I have tried using safari, chrome, firefox, netscape and the evil IE but still nothing works - However facebook chat notifications work no matter what!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FsPq4/2/ - works fine to me (Chrome). Sound is played every 2 sec even now when I'm typing this text in a different tab.

Comment: @kdzwinel is there a way of doing this without using jquery?

Comment: Yes, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/FsPq4/4/

Comment: @kdzwinel this is where im having troubles getting it to work, it's within an if/else statement that reads from a xml file. http://jsfiddle.net/DABZG/